# Update text values of TableViewCell content by using UIButton action inside TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on an app in which i am using UITableviewCell to display feed data. In Cell i am using multiple UIButtons to perform actions.
The main issue arise when i perform action through buttons the method is not called for the very first time(TableViewCell content is not updated). But when i press button second time it works fine.

Here is my code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell_Reels", for: indexPath) as! Cell_Reels
        cell.delegate = self
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.1) { [self] in
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 12.0, delay: 1, options: ([.curveLinear, .repeat]), animations: {() -> Void in
                cell.marqueeLabel.center = CGPoint.init(x: 35 - cell.marqueeLabel.bounds.size.width / 2, y: cell.marqueeLabel.center.y)
            }, completion:  { _ in })
        
            
            cell.likebutton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.FollowButton.tag = indexPath.row
            
            cell.shareBtn.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.shareBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonShare), for: .touchUpInside)
            
            
            let VideoStr = self.videos[indexPath.row]["media"].string ?? ""
            self.fullVideoUrl = "\(KeyConstant.KBaseImageURL)\(VideoStr)"
            //print("======", self.fullVideoUrl)
            
            cell.configureCell( videoUrl: self.fullVideoUrl)
            self.pausePlayeVideos()
            
            cell.totalViews.text = "\(self.videos[indexPath.row]["count_view"].string ?? "") Views"
            cell.nameLbl.text = self.videos[indexPath.row]["full_name"].string ?? ""
            cell.descLbl.text = self.videos[indexPath.row]["title"].string ?? ""
            cell.marqueeLabel.text = self.videos[indexPath.row]["title"].string ?? ""
            cell.idLbl.text = self.videos[indexPath.row]["id"].string ?? ""
            
            cell.likedLbl.text = self.videos[indexPath.row]["like_status"].string ?? ""
            cell.followedLbl.text = self.videos[indexPath.row]["follow_status"].string ?? ""
            
            self.currentLikesStr = self.videos[indexPath.row]["count_like"].string ?? ""
            cell.likesCountLabel.text = "\(self.currentLikesStr) Likes"
            
            
            self.followedStr = self.videos[indexPath.row]["follow_status"].string ?? ""
            print("followedStr       ppppppppppppppppppppppppp",followedStr, cell.idLbl.text!)
            if self.followedStr == "0"
            {
                cell.FollowButton .setTitle("Follow", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            }
            else
            {
                cell.FollowButton .setTitle("Following", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            }
            self.likedStr = self.videos[indexPath.row]["like_status"].string ?? ""
            print("likedStr -=-==-===-=-=-",likedStr, cell.idLbl.text!)
            if likedStr == "0"
            {
                let selectedImage = UIImage(named: "heart_y2_30x30") as UIImage?
                cell.likebutton.setImage(selectedImage, for: UIControl.State.normal)
            }
            else
            {
                let selectedImage = UIImage(named: "heart_y_30x30") as UIImage?
                cell.likebutton.setImage(selectedImage, for: UIControl.State.normal)
            }
            cell.CommentsCountLabel.text = "Comments"
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Button method decleration

```
func addFollowed(cell: Cell_Reels)
    {
followedStr = cell.followedLbl.text!
            let idstr = cell.idLbl.text
            print(userId, idstr ?? "", followedStr)
            
            let VideoidStr = cell.idLbl.text
            print("=====", VideoidStr!)
            
            let deviceid = "12345"
            //print(videoId)
            WebServiceHelper.sharedInstanceAPI.hitPostAPI(urlString: KeyConstant.APIFollow, params: ["user_id":userId, "device_id": deviceid, "device_type" : "iOS", "video_id":VideoidStr!], completionHandler: { (result: [String:Any], err:Error?) in
                //print(result)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    //MBProgress().hideIndicator(view: self.view)
                }
                if(!(err == nil))
                {
                    return
                }
                let json = JSON(result)
                
                let statusCode = json["status"].string
                //print(json)
                if(statusCode == "success")
                {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.1) { [self] in
                    self.followedStr = json["follow_status"].string ?? ""
                    cell.followedLbl.text = "\(self.followedStr)"
                    print(self.followedStr)
                    print(";;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;", self.followedStr)
                    if self.followedStr == "0"
                    {
                        cell.FollowButton .setTitle("Follow", for: UIControl.State.normal)
                        self.followedStr = "1"
                        self.arrayTempData[cell.FollowButton.tag] = 1
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cell.FollowButton .setTitle("Following", for: UIControl.State.normal)
                        self.followedStr = "0"
                        self.arrayTempData[cell.FollowButton.tag] = 0
                    }
                    }
                }
            })
            
            self.tblInstaReels.reloadData()
            self.followedStr = ""

}
```

This i defined in TableViewCell class

```
    protocol TableViewCellDelegate
{
    func addTapped(cell: Cell_Reels, Tlikes : String)
    func addFollowed(cell: Cell_Reels)
}


class Cell_Reels: UITableViewCell, ASAutoPlayVideoLayerContainer
{
    var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?
    
    
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var likedLbl : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var followedLbl : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var idLbl : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLbl : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var likesCountLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var CommentsCountLabel : UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var marqueeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgReels: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Bkview: UIView!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var PauseBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var descLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var shareBtn : UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var likebutton : UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var FollowButton : UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalViews : UILabel!
    
    var playerController: ASVideoPlayerController?
    var videoLayer: AVPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    
    
    var likestr = ""
    private(set) var liked = false
    private(set) var followed = false
    
    
    var VideoId = ""
    
    
    
    @IBAction func followed(_ sender: Any)
    {
        delegate?.addFollowed(cell: self)
    }
    
    
    
    @IBAction func like(_ sender: Any)
    {
        delegate?.addTapped(cell: self, Tlikes: self.likedLbl.text!)
    }
    
    
    
    func likeVideo()
    {
        print("==========", likestr)
    }
    
    
    
    var videoURL: String?
    {
        didSet {
            if let videoURL = videoURL
            {
                ASVideoPlayerController.sharedVideoPlayer.setupVideoFor(url: videoURL)
            }
            videoLayer.isHidden = videoURL == nil
        }
    }
    
    
    
    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        imgReels.layer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
        selectionStyle = .none
    }
    
    
    func configureCell(videoUrl: String?)
    {
        self.videoURL = videoUrl
    }
    
    
    override func prepareForReuse()
    {
        imgReels.imageURL = nil
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }
    
    
    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let horizontalMargin: CGFloat = 20
        let width: CGFloat = bounds.size.width - horizontalMargin * 2
        let height: CGFloat = (width * 0.9).rounded(.up)
        videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imgReels.layer.frame.width, height: imgReels.layer.frame.height)
    }
    
    
    func visibleVideoHeight() -> CGFloat
    {
        return imgReels.frame.size.height
        let videoFrameInParentSuperView: CGRect? = self.superview?.superview?.convert(imgReels.frame, from: imgReels)
        guard let videoFrame = videoFrameInParentSuperView,
            let superViewFrame = imgReels?.frame else {
             return 0
        }
        let visibleVideoFrame = videoFrame.intersection(superViewFrame)
        return visibleVideoFrame.size.height
    }
    
}
```

Comment: try disabling selection of `UITableViewCell` with `tableView.allowsSelection = false`

Comment: not working same result

Comment: PLzz share the code in Cell

Comment: Done please check

Answer (score 0):

1. in place of calling a separate method, use the addTarget method.
2. if you update anything in table view then perform all operations in cellForRowAt else after scrolling it reused the cell and it will create ambiguity
3. reload the table view in the main thread.